# How to move implementation of searching amicable numbers from imperative to functional?

Tags: java, functional-programming

I have a simple imperative implementation of the algorithm searching for amicable numbers. Now I try to make it more functional.

```
public static void search(){

    for(int i = 1; i < 10000; i++){
        for(int j = i+1; j < 10000; j++){
            if(isAmicable(i, j)){
                System.out.println(i + " " + j);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static boolean isAmicable(int i, int j){
    return sumProperDivisors(i) == j && sumProperDivisors(j) == i;
}

public static int sumProperDivisors(int num){
    int result = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < num; i++){
        if(num%i == 0) result +=i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

At first I've replaced loops with IntStreams in search() method.

```
public static void streamed(){
    IntStream.range(1, 10000).forEach(p -> {    
        IntStream.range(p+1, 10000).forEach(o -> {
            if(isAmicable(p, o)) System.out.println(p + " " + o);
        });
    });
}
```

I do not see any states or side-effects to be reduced. 
What else should be done in this implementation to meet the FP paradigm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative that produces a `Map` of all the amicable pairs instead of producing side effects:

```
Map<Integer,Integer> pairs =
    IntStream.range(1, 10000)
             .boxed()
             .flatMap(p -> IntStream.range(p+1, 10000)
                                    .filter(o -> isAmicable(p, o))
                                    .mapToObj(o -> new SimpleEntry<>(p,o)))
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Of course, in terms of performance this is quite bad, since you calculate `sumProperDivisors(i)` many times for the same `i`. It would be more efficient to calculate `sumProperDivisors(i)` once for each `i`, store the results in a `Map`, and check which pairs of `i` and `j` satisfy `sumProperDivisors(i) == j && sumProperDivisors(j) == i`.

Comment: nice idea, but then you declare a new variable. Could this Map pairs be replaced with another pure function?

Comment: @pobu it is a pure function, which has a return value. You have to return the amicable pairs somehow. What would you replace the Map with? You can eliminate the variable if you change the return type of `search()` from void to `Map<Integer,Integer>`. Then you simply return the result of the Stream pipeline.

Comment: There is an autoboxing (int -> Integer) in your solution and it makes performance really bad

Comment: @pobu did you run a benchmark, or are you just assuming that performance will be bad?

Comment: I have made a really simple benchmark with System.currentTimeMillis(). Here are the results: search() - 6002 sec; streamed() - 5634 sec; and pairs() - 9918 sec. I should have repeated it a few times to authenticate the result.

Answer (score 1):

Use filter instead `if(isAmicable(p, o))` and after forEach with `System.out.println(p + " " + o);` or map with forming message and afrer `System.out.println`